# Is it ok to send login details over GET request using SSL

Tags: security, ssl, jsonp

I'm restricted to using JSONP for API requests from a javascript app.

The entire javascript app will be hosted over SSL.

As we are limited to GET requests when using JSONP is it ok to send login credentials (username/password) to the API using a GET request?

I presume it wouldn't be if we weren't using SSL but it is ok because we are. Correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no. If you are using SSL, then in transport regardless of http method used your data is secure. But using POST instead of GET presumably adds one more level of protection for XSRF types of attack ( it does not, you need some form of explicit XSRF protection token, with POST or with GET). But most of login forms does not contain XSRF protection tokens mainly because this type of attack is designed to use already active login session of an unaware user.

So If you were not using ssl then POST/GET makes no big difference, and when you are using SSL nothing changes, attacks leveraging wrong methods aim in other parts/services of the system. Your password/login pair is as safe as in many current web apps.

P.S. You must be aware that depending of the configuration of your http server your password an login may be stored in log file dumping accesed url with parameters. (IEEE suffered such problem, they were using get method to login users).